# Responding to events when data changes

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a static class of lists which exposes several lists of largely static data.

However, that data can be modified within the application from time to time.

What I want is for my static class to reload the data based on an event raised by the code that will save any changes.

So I'm thinking I need to have and event and a delegate but I'm having a little trouble visualizing where the event and the delegate go as well as who raises the event and how etc.

All I have at this point is a static class which in it's constructor loads the data and a class elsewhere that updates data.

**edit**

Should I simply call another method in the static class to reload the data instead of worrying about raising events?  I mean, am I over complicating the code?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with SqlDependency, then I would definitely go with a simple method in your static class to invalidate your list and then force it to be reloaded next time it's accessed.

Comment: Try to describe your question more better. Describe how your classes interact, some methods. Just example. You can use list of string as example of your data

Comment: Is your data modified outside of your application? Do you have control of the code that performs the modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SqlDependency class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that's been available in C#/SQL 2005 since 2.0 to receive notifications inside your static class about changes to the data that you're caching as it is updated in SQL.

Then in your code, you don't have to create any kind of dependency across your classes to notify one another of changes.

Note that there is a performance impact for having notifications but if, as you say, this data is not changing very often, you should be OK. Also, there are certain restrictions on the SELECT statements that qualify for a notification. That is all listed at that link.

In one of my current projects, I have a similar class I use for configurations where I opted to not use dependency but instead used an invalidation method similar to what you're trying to do. The pattern is as follows:

```
    private static ReaderWriterLock lockObject = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public static void Invalidate()
    {
        try
        {
            lockObject.AcquireWriterLock(LockTimeoutMilliseconds);
            try
            {
                // Invalidate your content and reload here
            }
            finally
            {
                lockObject.ReleaseLock();
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            // The reader lock request timed out. Log this.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh cool.  There seem to be samples on using it with EF too which ideal.

Comment: Not exactly what I need but I get the point.  I just went with calling a method in the class to reload bits of the data that i needed.